# Thinking sphinx - indexing third model's name when its ID is saved as value through polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a polymorphic association between models A and B, where B.value can be:

- some searchable text
- the ID of model C

In A's index, I declare `indexes B.value`, so the searchable text is indexed, but so is the ID of C.

How do I set up the index so I can also search by C.name and not C.id?

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs, as: :bable

  define_index do
    indexes bs.value, as: :b_value
  end
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bable, polymorphic: true
  # :value -> can be searchable text or C.id
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  # :name -> I want to search by this, not :id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I'd probably set up separate associations with conditions on the `bable_type` column, and then use the new associations within the index definition.

An example (though I've not tested this):

```
has_many :bs_with_ids,    :as => :bable, lambda { where :bable_type => 'B1' }
has_many :bs_with_values, :as => :bable, lambda { where.not :bable_type => 'B1' }
```

And then in the index:

```
indexes bs_with_ids.c.name,   :as => :c_names
indexes bs_with_values.value, :as => :b_values

polymorphs bs_with_ids, :to => %w(B1)
polymorphs bs_with_values, :to => %w(B2 B3)
```

Now, I've written this assuming that specific types of B (given it's a polymorphic association) have the value column storing a C id (and have an association pointing to that C record) - in my example, B1 - and other types are storing searchable text in the `value` column instead (B2, B3). However, if there's no reliable way to determine whether `value` holds an ID or searchable text, then I guess this solution isn't going to work.

All that said: if it's possible, I highly recommend reworking your database so the column contents are a bit more consistent :)

Comment: How do you mean? Can you provide a small example?

Comment: I was thinking to add a column in B that contains C.name whenever B.value contains C.id. Then I could add an index to the new column.

Comment: ^ Added an example and a bit more detail.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, however B doesn't have C as an association. I can't use `bs_with_ids.c.name`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work:

1. Added a custom join
2. Added a custom index using the custom join

For example, in class A the index definition is:

```
# Custom join with C from the table 'cs':
join "LEFT OUTER JOIN cs c_value ON c_value.id = bs.value"

# Custom index based on custom join for when B.value contains C.id:
indexes "c_value.name", as: :custom_user

# This remains unchanged for when B.value contains searchable text:
indexes bs.value, as: :b_value
```